# Replace many keys by values from list in PDF

Tags: text, pdf, batch-processing

I have a lot of very large PDF files where I need to replace some strings in text. These strings are listed in a mapping table where every string has its corresponding string-value to be replaced with. Every PDF document has its own mapping table. For every PDF document, I need to replace all these keys using that document's mapping table.

I started to write Javascript in Acrobat Pro DC to do this for one document, but soon realised the API lacks functions to save changes to the document.

Is there another way or perhaps another program that would allow me to search and replace these codes en masse? At least for one document at a time. I *could* use the replace feature of Acrobat DC but the sheer amount of manual work makes this infeasible. This is not my field of expertise so any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: So you need to change multipy text strings with some other text strings?

Comment: Exactly. There are possibly hundreds of these replacement codes for every document, so doing the work manually is just not possible. I am looking for an automated way to do this at least on per-document basis.